# How much time should take to remodel this at an intermediate lvl?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

i would like to know how much time should take me at an intermediate lvl to remodel this chair, i need to know in order to accept or decline a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for us to measure the time that you will take with the model, everyone has a different approach, different techniques and workflows, some are faster some are slower.

I advise you to check on your own previous experience with similar models and be honest with yourself, accepting a job means that you will take a serious responsability so if you feel that this is project that you really **can** do and **respect the deadline** then do it.

Comment: perhaps i didnt express myself well, i already remodel the chair and took me like 6 hrs but since i figure it is too much time i decided to ask, thanks anyway